# Is the use of a dependent subquery justified in this case?

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, subquery

```
SELECT a.id,
       (SELECT ARRAY(
           SELECT c.id FROM table_c c
               JOIN table_d d ON d.id = c.id
               JOIN table_e e ON e.id = d.id
                WHERE a_id = a.id AND user_id = a.user_id
           )) AS first_subquery,
        a.first_field,
        a.second_field,
        a.third_field,
        a.fourth_field,
       (SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(
               'id', b.id,
               'first_field', b.first_field,
           )) FROM table_b b where  b.id = a.id) AS second_subquery
FROM table_a a;
```

It's hard to explain the problem without copy-pasting a complete query. This is almost the original query, except that names have been replaced.

Here are the use cases:

- For `first_subquery`, a JOIN could also work but it just felt more intuitive to write this dependent subquery. The dataset size is not large so performance might not become a bottleneck regardless of executing this subquery for each row of the main query
- For `second_subquery`, however, I am not sure I know a more convenient way to achieve the goal. And the goal is to collect each row from `table_a` along with a `jsonb` array of objects with matching rows from `table_b`. For simplicity, let's say you want to get football teams with the squads included as a list of objects for each.

I hope that this sample and my description are enough to understand what I would like to achieve. My impression is that `first_subquery` might get too inefficient as the dataset increases. The same could be true for `second_subquery` but I really like the readability and honestly speaking I haven't managed to come up with any alternative.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Co-related sub-queries are usually substantially slower as a corresponding derived table. But your sub-queries can be re-written to derived tables (using GROUP BY)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  by derived tables you mean moving those subqueries to the FROM clause or transforming them to JOINS and then grouping by `a.id`?

Comment: I am now trying to rewrite it as two JOINS with non-correlated subqueries but that predictably results in duplicate jsonb objects due to the number of different resulting tuples

Comment: Then you are not grouping in the derived tables. Something like: https://pastebin.com/U2uusZK6

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, oh, right, thank you so much. Joining them this way does indeed generate the desired result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Could be an *answer* to close the question ...